# Conditional format is running correctly

Tags: javascript, conditional-formatting

I am running a basic conditional format function, but for some reason, it seems to run through all of the conditions and also produces an undefined alert.

```js
function mark(grade) {
  if (grade <= 3) {
    alert("poor");
  } else if (grade > 3 && grade < 8) {
    alert("good");
  } else(grade > 8)
  alert("excellent");
}
alert(mark(2))
```

Comment: You're seeing `undefined` is because the function `mark` does not return anything. The default function return is `undefined`. The code also has syntax errors.

Comment: You should change all the `alert()` calls in the function to `return`. Then you can alert what it returns.

Comment: You don't put a condition after `else`. If you want another condition, it should be `else if`.

Comment: You can use switch statements for this.

Answer (score 0):

So apart from the typos and logical errors, try a ternary here:

```js
const mark = grade => grade <= 3 ?  "poor" : grade < 8 ? "good" : "excellent";
alert(2 + ":" + mark(2))

// for testing purposes:
console.log(4,mark(4))
console.log(7,mark(7))
console.log(9,mark(9))
```

your code fixed (Same as Nina's deleted code. I'll remove this if she undeletes)

```js
function mark(grade) {
  if (grade <= 3) return "poor"; // no need for else when you return 
  if (grade <  8) return "good"; // no need to test 3 again
                  return "excellent";
}
alert(mark(2))
```

Answer (score -1):

1) alert(mark(2)) -> call the mark function as parameter in alert! mark function not return anything so the last alert show "undefined"

2) the last "else" needs to be "else if"